# Sorting more than 2 strings in Assembly level language

Tags: x86-16

I have an assembly level language program, which compares 2 strings, but I need to compare 10 strings. How do I achieve this? My string comparison program is in a procedure.

```
; segments

data segment
data1 db 64 ,? ,64  dup(?)
data2 db 64 ,? ,64  dup(?)
data3 db 64 ,? ,64  dup(?)
data4 db 64 ,? ,64  dup(?)
data5 db 64 ,? ,64  dup(?)
data6 db 64 ,? ,64  dup(?)
data7 db 64 ,? ,64  dup(?)
data8 db 64 ,? ,64  dup(?)
data9 db 64 ,? ,64  dup(?)
data10 db 64 ,? ,64  dup(?)
ends

stack segment
    dw  128 dup(0)
ends

code segment
  main proc far
; set segment registers:

mov ax, data
mov ds, ax
move es,ax
call input
check data1,data2



; gets input from user
input proc
    lea dx, enter
        mov ah,09h
        int 21h
        call newline

        mov ah, 0ah
        lea dx,data1
        int 21h
        call newline

       mov ah, 0ah
       lea dx,data2
       int 21h
       call newline

       mov ah, 0ah
      lea dx,data3
      int 21h
      call newline

     mov ah, 0ah
    lea dx,data4
    int 21h
    call newline

    mov ah, 0ah
    lea dx,data5
    int 21h
    call newline

   mov ah, 0ah
   lea dx,data6
  int 21h
  call newline

 mov ah, 0ah
 lea dx,data7
 int 21h
 call newline

 mov ah, 0ah
 lea dx,data8
 int 21h
 call newline

 mov ah, 0ah
 lea dx,data9
 int 21h
 call newline

 mov ah, 0ah
 lea dx,data10
 int 21h
 call newline

ret
input endp


newline proc

    mov ah,02h
    mov dl,0ah
    int 21h

    mov dl,0dh
    int 21h

ret
newline endp

check macro a,b
local next,finish

 mov cx, 64 ;  buffer size to save string
 mov si,a
 mov di,b


 repe cmpsw ;comparing two strings with each other
 ja next
 jmp finish
next :
;swapping strings
 mov cx, 64
 mov si,a
 lea di,change
 rep movsb

 mov cx,64
 mov si,b
 mov di,a
 rep movsb

 mov cx,64
 lea si,change
 mov di,b
 rep movsw
finish: 
endm

ends

end main
```

Comment: Wake up!!!  5PM isn't here yet!

Comment: Read up on bubble sort (for example) - or any one of the 'related' posts on the right side of your post.

Answer (score 0):

There are several sorting algorithms. [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) for example. What is common among all of them is that they're based on comparison. You already have code for that, so you just need to have your existing code as a subroutine and invoke it for each pair of strings following the strategy of the sorting algorithm of your choice.

The subroutine could, for example, have a return value of *-1*, *0* or *1* based on *less-than*, *equal* or *greater-than* relation between the compared strings.